# Process finished with exit code -1 Python

Tags: python, flask, pyqt5

I have this code which is working good, as soon as the method is called, the code provides the expected results and the application is getting stopped. Not sure why the entire flask application is getting stopped. PyDt5 is a new library am working on and am unable to stop from quitting the application.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

def printhtmltopdf(html_in, pdf_filename):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage()

    def handle_pdfPrintingFinished(*args):
        print("finished: ", args)
        app.quit()

    def handle_loadFinished(finished):
        page.printToPdf(pdf_filename)

    page.pdfPrintingFinished.connect(handle_pdfPrintingFinished)
    page.loadFinished.connect(handle_loadFinished)

    page.setZoomFactor(1)
    page.setHtml(html_in)

    app.exec()

printhtmltopdf(
        Result,
        "File.pdf",
    )
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated